# Android Notification launch both onResume() and onCreate()

Tags: android

When I touch in the notification with my application running both onResume() and onCreate() are executed
My application has only one activity. What I need is to run onResume () if the application is running and onCreate () if not running

```
    Intent intentNot = new Intent(this, OfflineActivity.class);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Title", System.currentTimeMillis());

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title", "Text" , PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, intentNot, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));


    intentNot.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);



    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;


    mManager.notify(APP_ID_NOTIFICATION, notification);
```